# knowrob_mesh_reasoning not be found

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the knowrob and compile the knowrob_addons, it cannot find the dependency

*knowrob_mesh_reasoning*

. I tried to find it, but I found that the package know_mesh_reasoning on github  knowrob repository is removed. How can I deal with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69016/knowrob_mesh_reasoning-not-be-found/) by [Rikardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5410/rikardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

knowrob_mesh_reasoning has been moved into a private repository, but you should not need it for any package you want to use. The only packages depending on it are in such an early development phase that external users are not advised to use them.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-30**:
Then the dependency and/or package should be removed, I'd say. I just ran into the same issue. :-(

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-07-30**:
Why? That's a repository of different add-on packages, and rosmake shall work on all packages that other people are supposed to use. What's your use case that you need to run rosmake on the full knowrob_addons repository?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-30**:
It comes with the provided rosinstaller. In my case one package was somehow not being build when doing `rosmake roboearth`. So I did `rosmake --all`. I guess, if everything works as planned, nobody will ever find out that there is "intentionally broken" code hiding in that stack.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-30**:
I would say a cleaner way would be to move that piece of code out into a separate stack. While it was quite convenient to hide unused/broken code in a stack with rosbuild - we did the same - it gets annoying with catkin, since one usually compiles the whole workspace - at least I do.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-07-30**:
Well, it's neither unused nor broken, just not intended for public use. That's why it's not part of the knowrob stack itself, but in a separate repository. But I get your point and will see if I can move the packages such that everything that's public also builds.